# Entity Framework trying to create duplicate column

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using the Entity Framework.  The table already exists with the column my_column.  I added the property my_column to my class to access that column.  The program then seems to try to create the column, but fails since it already exists.

```
Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'my_column' in table 'my_table' is specified more than once.
```

Is there a way to get it to not try to create the column and recognize that the existing one is the one it should use?

Comment: Do you have data that you need on that column in db? If no, you can try `update-database -v -f` or even delete the whole table so that migration will be re-generated.

Comment: Did you change the data type?  Or the capitalization?

Comment: @IsabelHM not any code to post really, Entity framework is a black box to me and it tries to make that column on its own

Comment: @Steve I used to get around this by deleting the column and letting it create it.  Then any subsequent runs it would successfully know that the column was there and not try to recreate it.

But I'm in a situation where I can't delete it, hence this question.

Comment: @DStanley Yes correct type and capitalization.

Comment: If you use Visual Studio DbContextGenerator, try right click all the auto-generated DbContext files and regenerate it. (This is EF6 in VS2013)

Answer (score 0):

You could edit the migration before updating the batabase. Remove duplicates and see what happens.

```
            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(

            name: "InvoiceConsumers",

            columns: table => new

            {

               …,

                InvoiceId = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),

                InvoiceId1 = table.Column<int>(nullable: true)

            },

            constraints: table =>

            {

                table.PrimaryKey("PK_InvoiceConsumers", x => x.Id);

                table.ForeignKey(

                    name: "FK_InvoiceConsumers_Consumers_ConsumerId",

                    …);

                table.ForeignKey(

                    name: "FK_InvoiceConsumers_Invoices_InvoiceId",

                    …

                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);

                table.ForeignKey(

                    …

                    column: x => x.InvoiceId1,

                    principalTable: "Invoices",

                    …

                    );

            });
```